# ASP.NET: How to create a custom Pager for GridView?

Tags: asp.net, pager

Is it possible to create a custom Pager for the GridView control of ASP.NET that looks liek this?
[image: Pager]

If so, can anyone give me some ideas or some starting code into how to create it?

Thank you.

Comment: Do you want to alter only the visuals or are you after some radical behavioral changes to the pager?

Comment: The Next and Previous have to be Buttons or Image Buttons and it has to have a similar format to this one with the same styling but I cannot achieve this with the Default Pager that comes with GridView.

Comment: @codingbiz I have tried to create something using PagerSettings and PagerStyle but I was not able to create something that functions and looks like this. I was wondering if there's anyway to create something similar to this using Custom Grid View Pagers if so, can you give me some hints or some code to get me started?

Comment: What exactly have you tried so far? Because this should be easily achievable with the embedded pager, just by altering few css rules...

Comment: But the default pager doesn't have "Previous" and "Next" it only has the following modes: 
    Numeric
    NumericFirstLast
    NextPrevious
    NextPreviousFirstLast
Is there any other way to do this? Custom Templates? or maybe PagerTemplate?

Comment: This link should help you [Custom Paging in GridView](http://www.codeproject.com/Tips/402965/Custom-Paging-in-GridView) and [GridView Custom Paging](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/16238/GridView-Custom-Paging). Search StackOverflow and google for similar question

Comment: I want to do something similar to this: http://www.asp.net/community/recognition/hall-of-fame                                                                                            Previous 1 2 3 4 5 ... 99 Next

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just need fixed LinkButtons for previous & next and a LinkButton inside a Repeater control for the individual pages.

Have a look at this page for details: [Custom Paging with the ASP.NET Repeater control](http://www.dotnetcurry.com/ShowArticle.aspx?ID=345)

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion but I'm using an ObjectDataSource in my grid view so I cannot use stuff like Repeater1.DataSource = page
                  Repeater1.DataBind() in my code behind, do you have an idea of how to create this using custom templates or manybe PagerTemplate ? Thankyou.